# Fixing a guest screen resolution in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, resolution

I was required to develop a Windows app UI for a fixed resolution - it doesn't matter if it makes sense or not, the customer requires it. I'm using a Windows Server 2003 VirtualBox VM as the development environment; my host machine has much higher resolution.

Is there any way to select and fix the OS resolution and stop VirtualBox changing it by any kind of scaling? I can't see the requested resolution when I open Display Properties on the guest OS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I tried this, and might work for you. Under the Machine menu, there is an option to auto-resize the guest OS's resolution to fit the monitor you are using. I got the resolution you did by enabling this option, manually resizing the window to get the resolution I wanted, then DISABLING auto-resize. Then, it's "stuck" there and I can resize the window, move it around, resolution doesn't change. Only problem was the taskbar. While you are doing the resize, might help to minimize it to get the exact resolution

Answer (score 10):

For my setup, neither `CustomVideoMode1` nor `setvideomodehint` nor `MaxGuestResolution` worked. So, I looked up

`vboxmanage getextradata $YOUR_VM_NAME enumerate`

and changed

`Key: GUI/LastGuestSizeHint, Value: 800,600`

to

`Key: GUI/LastGuestSizeHint, Value: 1920,1080`

with

`vboxmanage setextradata $YOUR_VM_NAME GUI/LastGuestSizeHint 1920,1080`

Comment: This was hugely helpful in letting me set the size of a VM in Vagrant + Virtualbox. I wanted to be able to resize the VM to any resolution after it was booted, but always have it start up and switch to a certain resolution, so I added `vb.customize ['setextradata', :id, 'GUI/LastGuestSizeHint','1280,800']` to my Vagrantfile and it is working great.

Comment: Same as the answer above, except I had to escape the forward slash within the key (or perhaps, it works as is as long as you are you using single quotes):

vb.customize ["setextradata", :id, "GUI\/LastGuestSizeHint", "1920,1080"]

Comment: @GeorgeSmith that is because you used double quotes which require escaping while allowing for variables and parameter expansion as well as other string interpolations. Single quoted string literals do not.

Comment: @MikaFeiler,
Thank you so much for explaining.
Just some context. I tried to use your examples as :after triggers in Vagrant and from within the Vagrantfile (Vagrant provides a way to call vobxmanage from within the file).
It appears that after logging in, the resolution is as expected, but the initial login screen resolution is still 800x600. It works fine after logging in and logging back in.
If you have any suggestions about the initial login screen, please, respond.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6):

While the VM is running, define your custom resolution using this command:

`vboxmanage setextradata "[VM NAME]" CustomVideoMode1 1600x900x32`

While the VM is running, execute the following command to switch to your new resolution:

`vboxmanage controlvm "[VM NAME]" setvideomodehint 1600 900 32`

It should switch to the new resolution immediately.

For this to work you must have VirtualBox Guest Extensions installed in the VM.

Comment: Does not work FOR ME on Windows 10. The vbox window does not change its resolution.

Comment: You must have VirtualBox Guest Extensions installed in your VM for those commands to work.

Comment: Brilliant! Worked for me in Windows 7 (Tiny7). Got an error setting before boot of VM, but second one worked after a few seconds.

Comment: @Sun I did write "While the VM is running" so I am not sure why you are surprised it didn't work before it booted.

Comment: For me this worked only using the `VBoxSVGA` graphics controller on a Linux host with a Win 10 guest.

Answer (score 5):

Try installing Guest Additions. It provides lots more features to the guest OS. From there, you can leverage the resolution you want and lock the screen in that position.

Comment: I have Guest Additions. Problem is the resolution I need is never allowed as in the resolution selection slider in guest OS.

Comment: What is the resolution, exactly?

Comment: You may need to install the guest additions when running in safe mode. I have seen several instances where the video driver did not completely install when not in safe mode - particularly for 3D acceleration.

Comment: Requested resolution is 1440x900 (HP LE1901w native) host resolution is 1920x1080

Comment: So I tried this, and might work for you. Under the Machine menu, there is an option to auto-resize the guest OS's resolution to fit the monitor you are using. I got the resolution you did by enabling this option, manually resizing the window to get the resolution I wanted, then DISABLING auto-resize. Then, it's "stuck" there and I can resize the window, move it around, resolution doesn't change. Only problem was the taskbar. While you are doing the resize, might help to minimize it to get the exact resolution

Answer (score 4):

Even with Guest Additions installed, my remote Windows is not able to give me my
wished 1920x1080 so I used this solution

```
vboxmanage startvm "mymachine";vboxmanage controlvm "mymachine" setvideomodehint 1920 1080 32
```

Comment: Does not work FOR ME on Windows 10. The VM does not boot anymore. How to revert this setting?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem as described above nothing was working even the manual setting of screen resolution, I solved my problem with checking some things:

1. In VirtualBox Manager GUI checked my OS version: I have chosen Windows 8.1 64 bit, but guest OS was 32 bit which, was the main problem
2. Solution: new machine with win 8.1 32 bit OS and linked to an old virtual hard drive
3. Setting machine custom resolution with VBoxManage command line

   ```
   VBoxManage.exe setextradata "[Virtual Machine Name]" CustomVideoMode1 1366x768x32
   ```

Answer (score 1):

From with Vagrant file - see the last line with **LastGuestSizeHint**, I had to escape the slash after GUI in order for this to work:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "codeup/Ubuntu-20.04-GUI"
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.gui = true
        vb.name = "Eclipse"
        vb.memory = 2048
        vb.cpus = 2
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--vram", 256]
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--clipboard", "bidirectional"]
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--draganddrop", "bidirectional"]
        vb.customize ["setextradata", :id, "GUI\/LastGuestSizeHint", "1920,1080"]
    end
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for: a programmatic way to tell VBox to resize the window, thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Hope things work out end to end :).