# Ubuntu minimal in VirtualBox can't get fullscreen resolution

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, resolution

*Before possibly downvoting or closing/flagging this post as duplicate please notice that I'm working with a CLI Ubuntu so installing virtualbox guest additions doesn't help. I have already tried it. I have also tried other solutions: for example [this](https://superuser.com/questions/301464/fixing-a-guest-screen-resolution-in-virtualbox) or [this](https://superuser.com/questions/374963/using-ubuntu-server-in-full-screen-mode-virtualbox/374971) and many other posts. I wasn't sure if I should ask this question in macOS, Ubuntu or SuperUser stackexchange so I asked it here.*

---

I have an Ubuntu Minimal 16.04.3 LTS tty1 installed on VirtualBox Version 5.1.30 r118389 on my MacBook running macOS EL Capitan version 10.11.6. When I fullscreen the window with <kbd>left cmd ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> the working window of the CLI Ubuntu does not scale up.

#### Expected solution:

Almost all of the solutions I have found on the internet require editing these files:

- `/etc/default/grub`
- `/etc/grub.d/00_header`

#### Steps:

1. Hold <kbd>shift  ⇧</kbd>  while booting to go to GRUB menu
2. press <kbd>C</kbd> to go to GRUB CLI
3. enter the command `set pager=1` to make sure you see long returns
4. enter the command `vbeinfo` or `videoinfo` and press enter multiple times to see all of your options for screen resolution. On my mac I have a screen resolution of `2880x1800` and from vbeinfo I chose `1152x864x32`.
5. press <kbd>shift  ⇧</kbd> +<kbd>esc</kbd> to go back to GRUB menu and then boot in normally
6. When booted edit `/etc/default/grub` with superuser and applying either of the edits:

   - changing the value of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quite"` to `quiet vga=0x0365` or `nomodeset` or `quiet text vga=0x160` or `splash vga=792` ...
   - uncommenting the line `GRUB_GFXMODE=...` and editing the value to the one selected in step 4
   - Adding a line below as `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD=...` with the same value as above or `keep`
7. Editing the file `/etc/grub.d/00_header` with superuser privilages and apply the edits:

   - editing the line `if [ "x${GRUB_GFXMODE}" = "x" ] ; then GRUB_GFXMODE=1152x864x32 ; fi` to match the resolution chosen in step 4
   - Adding the line `if [ "x${GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD}" = "x" ] ; then GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD=1152x864x32 ; fi` below
   - Find the line `set gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE}` and add `set gfxpayload=${GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD}` below
8. update grub `update-grub` or `update-grub2` with superuser
9. reboot

During the booting process or in the GRUB, the CLI matech the window size but when it boots up the main command line is still small! I have tried other resolutions and other possible combinations but none works. I would appreciate if you could help me find the problem and solve it.

Answer (score 1):

*I think I have found the solution. Well partly! With the below solution you will be able to adjust the resolution to any of the options available in `GRUB>vbeinfo` but it will not adjust automatically to fit the window.*

#### Solution:

(From [this post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=33214#p152720)) the only file you need to edit is `/etc/default/grub`. So after step 5, edit the file and

1. change the value of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash quite"` to `nomodeset`
2. find `GRUB_GFXMODE=...` line and add `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=...` afterwards, with the resolution you chose from step 4.

And then continue from step 8 to update GRUB and reboot.

**P.S.** I also tried the issue with Ubuntu 17.10 on Windows 10, so the issue has nothing to do with the version of Ubuntu on either host OS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install in guest OS virtual box guest additions and on some Ubuntu versions GCC support too to get the biggest possible size of screen.